# Query Redshift Database from localhost web app?

Tags: php, database, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to connect my html/css/js web app on my localhost to a separate redshift database. I don't have access to the key/secret, so the [SDK for PHP](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/guide/getting-started/basic-usage.html) won't work for me.

Are there alternative options? I feel like I'm on the wrong track. I'm trying to query the redshift database and build some html/css graphics on my localhost.

**Attempted code, per Ketan**

`$dbconn = pg_connect("host=endpoint dbname=name user=UN password=PW")
    or die('Could not connect: ' . pg_last_error());`

**And error...**

Warning: pg_connect(): Unable to connect to PostgreSQL server: could not connect to server: Connection timed out (0x0000274C/10060) Is the server running on host "endpoint" and accepting TCP/IP connections on port ####? in results.php on line 38

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any key/secret to query the Redshift cluster.

Think of it as a usual PostgreSQL-based database. All you need are the following:

- Redshift cluster URL and port
- Name, username and password of the database that contains your table

Comment: thanks for your answer. I'm pretty new to databases... could you provide additional context? I included my new code/error in the original post.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [redshift-sql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redshift-sql) in AWS lambda. Then you could invoke the lambda from web app.

```
var config = {
  host: 'rs-cluster.us-east-1.redshift.amazonaws.com',
  db: 'dev',
  user: 'rsadmin',
  password: 'rsPassword'
};
var rssql = require('redshift-sql')(config);
var query = 'select * from myTable limit 10';

rssql(query, function cb(err, result) {
  if (err) {
    return console.error(err);
  }
  // do stuff 
});
```